# Django Admin Inlines

Tags: django

```
class MyParentModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
      if formset.model._meta.db_table=='MyInLIneModel':
```

In the debugger

```
formset.model = {ModelBase} <class 'my app.models.MyInLineModel'>
```

I am able to check by formset.model._meta.db_table which is 'MyInLineModel'. 
I know this is not the right way.
can any one suggest a clean way to check the model name.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you do this but you can check it this way:

```
from your_app.models import SomeModel

class MyParentModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
      if formset.model == SomeModel:
          pass
```